# SyntaxError: final inesperado de la entrada JSON y en la pestaña de red, la vista previa está configurada como vacía

Tags: javascript, php, sql, datatables

Actualmente estoy trabajando en un sistema de administración de bienes. Estoy en la parte de busqueda de un bien mediante su codigo. Ahora bien a la hora de pintar el resultado de dicha busqueda me arroja

> SyntaxError: final inesperado de la entrada JSON

Así que voy a la pestaña de red donde está mi consulta sql y sorpresa, sorpresa aparece en blanco (vacío), ni siquiera nuestra un error o algo y ahí también estaba en lo mismo ya que eso nunca me había pasado. Gracias por leerme

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi Sql

```
 <?php
$valor = $_POST['valor'];
$op = $_POST['opcion'];

if ($op === 'B') {
    include
        '../modelo/conexiondb.php';

    try {
        $sql = $conexion->prepare('SELECT fecha, nombre as clasificacion, tipo_de_bien, concepto, cantidad, n_bien, n_control, nombre_y_descripcion, departamentos as departamento, v_unitario, estado as estatus from bienes INNER JOIN clasificacion on bienes.clasificacion=clasificacion.id_d INNER JOIN concepto_mov_incorporados on bienes.concep_mov=concepto_mov_incorporados.codigo INNER JOIN departamentos on bienes.departamento=departamentos.id_depa INNER JOIN estatus on bienes.estatus=estatus.id where n_bien=?');
        $sql->bind_param('s', $value);
        $sql->execute();

        $respuesta = $sql->get_result()->fetch_all();

        $sql->close();

        $conexion->close();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //En caso de un error, tomar la excepcion
        $respuesta = array('respuesta' => $e->getMessage());
    }
    echo json_encode($respuesta);
}

?>
```

JS

```
const d=document; 

d.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e=>{
detectarOpcion();
});
function detectarOpcion () {
let 
$input=d.getElementById('valor'),
$boton=d.getElementById('btn-buscar');
$boton.addEventListener('click', e=>{
let $select=d.getElementById('select').value;
        const datos=new FormData();
        datos.append('valor', $input.value);
        datos.append('opcion', $select) 
    fetch('./modelo/nbien_busqueda_y_ncontrol.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: datos,
    })
.then(res=>{return res.ok ?(res.json()) :Promise.reject(res);})
.then(data=>{ console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    let respuesta='';
    for(let i in data ){
        respuesta += `<tr>
            <td>${data[i].fecha}</td>
            <td>${data[i].clasificacion}</td>
            <td>${data[i].tipo_de_bien}</td>
            <td>${data[i].concepto}</td>
            <td>${data[i].cantidad}</td>
            <td>${data[i].n_bien}</td>
            <td>${data[i].n_control}</td>
            <td>${data[i].nombre_y_descripcion}</td>
            <td>${data[i].departamento}</td>
            <td>${data[i].v_unitario}</td>
            <td>${data[i].estatus}</td>
         
        </tr>`
        
    }
    d.querySelector('.contenedor-datatables').classList.remove('none');
    d.querySelector('.tbody').innerHTML=respuesta;
    


})
.catch(err=>{
console.log(err); 
})
.finally(()=>{
console.log('Esto se ejecutará independientemente del resultado de la Promesa Fetch')
 })

 })

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#bienes-busqueda').DataTable();
 });
```

Encabezados de la solicitud
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Envio de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has verificado desde php que la consulta esté devolviendo resultados?

Comment: En Phpmyadmin si. Pero en el localhost ¿para verificar una consulta no es la pestaña red e ir a la ventana de vista previa del archivo php? Si es así está en blanco (es la imagen adjunta)

Comment: Puede pasar de que la condicion donde envias tu json no se esté ejecutando o simplemente no está entrando a la validación, prueba lo siguiente create manualmente una structura json en php enviala con echo asi como haces dentro de tu if ejemplo: echo json_encode('{"json": "Hola mundo"}); si al revisar en tu red te envia eso, quiere decir que en tu php la condicional no se está cumpliendo

Comment: Podrías editar tu pregunta y mostrar una foto de tu encabezado, en tu consola web en Encabezado

Comment: En el apartado de encebezados podrias mostrar el encabezado de respuesta, jaja perdón por no aclararte esa parte, volverias a editar la pregunta para añadir esa parte

Comment: probe con lo que me dijjiste de echo json_encode('{"json": "Hola mundo"}). Solo que fue sustituir la variable $respuesta(donde está el resultado mi consulta) por ('{"json": "Hola mundo"}) y si lo recibió en la ventana de vista previa, ¿Alguna idea? Además agregue la imagen con los encabezados

Comment: Ya te agrego una respuesta para explicarte el porqué pasa esto

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Si analizamos tu codigo php tienes una condicion con la cual debe cumplirse para enviar tu JSON

```
<?php
$valor = $_POST['valor'];
$op = $_POST['opcion']; //** VERIFICAR ESTRICTAMENTE SI RECIBE EL VALOR DE TIPO STRING 'B' */

if ($op === 'B') { /** ESTO DEBE CUMPLIRSE SI O SI PARA ENVIAR UN JSON */
    include
        '../modelo/conexiondb.php';

    try {
        
        /** CODIGO... */

       
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        /** EN CASO DE QUE FALLE MAS CODIGO... */
    }
    echo json_encode($respuesta); //** ESTO SE ENCUENTRA DENTRO DE UNA CONDICION QUE NO SE CUMPLE POR LO TANTO JAMAS ENVIARÁ EL JSON */
}
```

Tienes una variable llamada `$op` Esta variable puede que esté recibiendo un valor distinto de `'B'` o simplemente `$_POST['opcion']` no esté recibiendo datos

Debes asegurarte de que envias el valor exactamente igual para que cumpla tu condicion

Comment: Mas que todo tu problema sería de envio de datos, verificar que si esté llegando los datos correctos para entrar en tu condicion

Comment: Si, si se esta enviando  la 'B'. Ya edite mi respuesta

Comment: agregate esto despues de tu condicion echo json_encode(var_dump($op)); y comentame que trae, deberia salirte algo como esto -->   string(1) "B"

Comment: Me arroja string(1) "B" null

Comment: Hagamos una segunda prueba, comenta todo dentro de condicion y solamente y dentro de la condicion agrega la siguiente linea echo json_encode(var_dump($op)); quiero descargar que tu try catch está afectando

Comment: tambien validamos si la condicion se está cumpliendo de paso

Comment: Si al ver en red no hay nada arrojado quiere decir que tu condicion no se cumple, pero si te arroja algo string(1) "B" null en teoria esto, puede de que el codigo que tienes dentro de tu funcion este afectando

Comment: <?php 
$value=$_POST['valor'];
$op=$_POST['opcion'];
if ($op=="B") {
 include '../modelo/conexiondb.php';
 echo json_encode(var_dump($op));
}
 ?> La modifique asi y me sigue arrojando string(1) "B" null

Comment: Ok listo, hagamos una prueba definitva, vuelve a restaurar tu codigo como tenias inicialmente la unica diferencia es que en la parte donde mandas tu json_encode($respuesta) lo haras de la siguiente manera echo json_encode(var_dump($respuesta));

Comment: Me comentas que te trae

Comment: string(1) "B" nullarray(1) { [0]=> array(11) { [0]=> string(10) "2016-09-15" [1]=> string(12) " INFORM�TICA" [2]=> string(6) "mueble" [3]=> string(26) "Incorporaci�n por Traspaso" [4]=> int(1) [5]=> string(7) "5133400" [6]=> string(12) "P3-COM-00031" [7]=> string(13) "CPU SIN MARCA" [8]=> string(18) " UNIDAD DE COMPRAS" [9]=> float(170) [10]=> string(11) "incorporado" } } null

Comment: Me parece extraño que te sí te arroje resultados pero este no los envie, trata de limpiar tu codigo, algo nos debemos estar saltando, utiliza tus importaciones al principio de la linea, mete el echo json_encode($respuesta) dentro de tu try

Comment: Aún nada sigue retornando vacio :(

Comment: Hagamos algo, declaremos tu variable $respuesta antes del try catch, despues cambiemos el fetch_all() de tu consulta por un fetch_array(), probemos así

Comment: Aún nada sigue en blanco